# Modular Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

$K,P,C$ are $ 2*2$ matrices such that $(KP)$ $ (mod 26) $ $ =  $ $ C $

For example we have $ P $ $ = $ $\begin{bmatrix} 8 & 17 \\ 13 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} $ and $ C $ $ = $ $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 22 \\ 20 & 21 \\ \end{bmatrix} $ . I want to find $ K $ .

The approach I am using is first I find $ P^{-1} $ .

$E = P^{-1} $ $ mod (26) $ $ = $ $\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 13 \\ 9 & 8 \\ \end{bmatrix} $

$R = det(P) $ $ mod (26) $ $  = 19 $  . $Modular$ $inverse$ of $R$ w.r.t to $26$ is $11$

So $ K = (R*(CE))mod(26) $

$ K $ $ = $ $\begin{bmatrix} 16 & 25 \\ 21 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} $ but the answer is $ K $ $ = $ $\begin{bmatrix} 22 & 3 \\9 & 6 \\ \end{bmatrix} $.

What is my error ? What is the correct way to find $K$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. Like you said $\det(P)^{-1}\equiv 11\text{ mod } 26$ which means
\begin{align}
P^{-1} \equiv 11 
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -17\\
-13 & 8
\end{bmatrix}
\equiv 
\begin{bmatrix}
18 & 21\\
13 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ mod } 26.
\end{align}

Finally, we see that
\begin{align}
CP^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 22\\
20 & 21
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
18 & 21\\
13 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
which is the desired answer.